# How can I do a full text search in CQ5 for content modified in the last 2 months?

Tags: java, search, jcr, aem

I'm trying do a full text search over the content in CQ using the built in [query builder api](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html).  This works fine but now I want to limit the search results to those that have been modified in the last 2 months.  I have looked at using the [relative date time predicate](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/RelativeDateRangePredicateEvaluator.html).  The properties I'm using are:

```
   QueryBuilder builder = sling.getService(QueryBuilder.class);
   String fulltextSearchTerm = request.getParameter("q");

   Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   map.put("relativedaterange", "@jcr:content/cq:lastModified");
   map.put("relativedaterange.lowerBound", "-2M");
   map.put("fulltext", fulltextSearchTerm);
   map.put("path", "/content/test/");
   map.put("type", "cq:Page");
   map.put("orderby", "@jcr:content/cq:lastModified");
   map.put("orderby.sort", "desc");

   Query query = builder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map), resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class));
```

This gives me search results, but does not limit them to those modified in the last 2 months.  Am I using these properties correctly or do I need to set some other value?

Answer (score 4):

The `relativedaterange` key needs to be `relativedaterange.property`.  This is shown on the java doc for the parent class [DateRangePredicateEvaluator](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/DateRangePredicateEvaluator.html).  And from using the query builder debugger it shows you don't need the `@` sign at the begging of the value.

So ultimately it ends up as:

```
  map.put("1_relativedaterange.property", "jcr:content/cq:lastModified");
  map.put("1_relativedaterange.lowerBound", "-2M");
```

Answer (score 0):

For quick testing of your query you can access 
http://x.x.x.x:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html 
and enter the parameters that you need to add to predicate group. Add these to predicate group and you should get the results.

```
path=/content/geometrixx
type=cq:Page
1_relativedaterange.property=jcr:content/cq:lastModified
1_relativedaterange.lowerBound=-2M
```

Here "`relativedaterange`" is the name of this Predicate Evaluator

Here 2M means 2 months, other options that are available like *1s 2m 3h 4d 5w 6M 7y (one second, two minutes, three hours, four days, five weeks, 6 months, 7 years).*, refer http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/RelativeDateRangePredicateEvaluator.html for more details.